# Azure Identity: Custom token validation to validate issuers in a multi tenant app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, asp.net-identity

I followed [Microsofts article](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration) to implement my own issuer validation ("Customizing token validation" is the headline of the section).

This seemed to work with JWT-Tokens issued in an **app-only** context, but failed when the first call to my API was a JWT token issued through **user delegation**.

I found that this line of code is causing the problem:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration);
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
  var existingOnTokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
  options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
  {
       await existingOnTokenValidatedHandler(context);
      // Your code to add extra configuration that will be executed after the current event implementation.
      options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new[] { /* list of valid issuers */ };
      options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[] { /* list of valid audiences */};
  }
});
```

This is the original code from the link I posted above.
I implemented my own issuer validation in the following way:

```
        services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {                
            var existingOnTokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;
            options.TokenValidtionParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                await existingOnTokenValidatedHandler(context);
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                var validTenants = FileTenantStore.Tenants.Select(x => x.AzureAdTenantId).ToList();
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = GetValidIssuers(validTenants);
                options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = ValidateIssuers;
            };
        });
```

I have a multi tenant app, so I need to let only some tenants pass and reject the most.

This solution behaves a little strange:

- Calling the API with an App-Only token works always.
- Calling the API with a Delegated token fails with the following error message and does not even jump into the callback:

> Failed to validate the token.
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException:
> IDW10303: Issuer:
> 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{OUR_TENANT_ID}/v2.0',
> does not match any of the valid issuers provided for this application.
> at Microsoft.Identity.Web.Resource.AadIssuerValidator.Validate(String
> actualIssuer, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters
> validationParameters)
> at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateIssuer(String
> issuer, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters
> validationParameters)
> at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken
> jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
> at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String
> token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken&
> validatedToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()

So in this case "OnTokenValidated" is ***never*** called.

- Calling the API with an App-Only token **on the first time**, and then later with a delegated token works fine.

I could fix this problem with moving the lines in the "OnTokenValidated"-Callback one level above:

```
        services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {                
            var existingOnTokenValidatedHandler = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;

            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
            var validTenants = FileTenantStore.Tenants.Select(x => x.AzureAdTenantId).ToList();
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = GetValidIssuers(validTenants);
            options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = ValidateIssuers;
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {                  
                await existingOnTokenValidatedHandler(context);
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";

            };
        });
```

I could even remove the callback "OnTokenValidated" now, but this does not feel right, because of the Microsoft article that is giving clear instructions.
Can I do it like this, or is my solution a security problem?

Comment: What the returned by `GetValidIssuers(validTenants)`? Based on the error message, `'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{OUR_TENANT_ID}/v2.0'`, does not match any of the valid issuers returned by `GetValidIssuers(validTenants)`. I guess that it returns the v1.0 version format: `'https://sts.windows.net/{TENANT_ID}'`.

Comment: You are right. It returns an array with addresses like "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant_id}/v2.0" and also "https://sts.windows.net/{TENANT_ID}". Both.

Comment: Can you take a JWT token and decode in https://jwt.ms/ to see what is the issuer (`iss` claim)? https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#sample-tokens

Comment: You got me wrong. I am a 100% sure the token is fine. The delegated token also works perfectly, after an application token was used. The question is: Why is OnTokenValidated not executed the first time my API is called with a user delegated JWT (iss is correct, I did this already)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in netcore>3 could you use AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication extension method. Set subscribeToOpenIdConnectMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents to true and enable debug logging to look at the event that terminate the check for your particular token.

Based on your code :

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration,
    jwtBearerScheme: JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true);
```

Comment: please can you elaborate "enable debug logging to look at the event that terminate the check for your particular token". sorry for my ignorance, but if you mean debug console then none of the events are reported. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [Web API Troubleshooting](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Web-API-Troubleshooting) and [Logging](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Logging) section to enable more traces during development process